# Move 2 nodes to the side without affecting the rest of the layout

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the [following dot layout](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20%7B%0A%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Drectangle%5D%20a%20b%20c%0A%0A%20%20a%20-%3E%20b%20b%20-%3E%20c%0A%0A%20%20b%20-%3E%20g1%20%5Bdir%3Dback%2Cconstraint%3Dfalse%5D%0A%20%20b%20-%3E%20g2%20%5Bdir%3Dback%2Cconstraint%3Dfalse%5D%0A%0A%20%20g1%20-%3E%20g2%20%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%0A%7D%0A):

```
digraph {
  a b c

  a -> b b -> c

  b -> g1 [dir=back,constraint=false]
  b -> g2 [dir=back,constraint=false]

  g1 -> g2 [style=invis]
}
```

[image: result of the dot layout above]

I would like g1 and g2 to be closer to each other and vertically centered around b like this:

[image: what I want instead]

I tried with a subgraph and cluster for g1 and g2 and with some invisible edges. I never managed to do anything good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to set **rankdir=LR** to make node alignment vertical instead of horizontal.  Then use **rank=same** to keep a, b, and c aligned.

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR  // now alignment is vertical

  {rank=same
    a b c
  }
  a -> b
  b -> c

  b -> g1 [dir=back] 
  b -> g2 [dir=back] 
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this graph is part of a larger one. Is there a solution that would allow me to keep the rest of the graph untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Shortish answer: No.  Because you are using the **dot** algorithm with **rankdir=TB** (default), all the nodes will be positioned on a horizontal rank (or row in this case).
However, you can post-process the result to modify the positioning. (Look for **-n** option here https://graphviz.org/doc/info/command.html)
Here is a small **gvpr** (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) script that will modify ("slide down") the positions of every node that has a new **slideDown=1** attribute.  (Yes, the Graphviz language allows you to make up your own attributes).
Your input, modified:

```
digraph {
  a b c
  g1 [slideDown=1]
  g2 [slideDown=1]
  
  a -> b b -> c
  b -> g1 [dir=back,constraint=false]
  b -> g2 [dir=back,constraint=false]
  g1 -> g2 [style=invis]
}
```

The **gvpr** script:

```
/*******************************************
  assumes rankdir=TB & no sliding down from bottom rank
*******************************************/
BEGIN{
  int   R=0, rPos[], Rank2P[], P2Rank[];
  float  YP;
}
N{
  YP=$.Y;
  rPos[YP]=1;
}
BEG_G{  // resets the graph traverse
 for (rPos[YP]){
   Rank2P[++R]=YP;
   P2Rank[YP]=R;
 }
}
N [slideDown=="1"]{
  float  nextY;
  nextY=Rank2P[P2Rank[$.Y]-1];
  $.oldPos=$.pos;
  $.pos=(string)$.X + "," + (string)(nextY+($.Y-nextY)/2);
}
```

the **bash** command line:
`dot myFile.gv |gvpr -cf slideNodes.gvpr  |neato -n -Tpng >myFile.png`
Giving:
[image]